# How can I update static list1 from list2 without loop How to achieve this the way LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

How can I update static list1 from list2 without loop
How to achieve this the way LINQ lambda expression

```
     public class State
    {
        public int SID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SCode { get; set; }
        public string SAbbrevation { get; set; }
    }

     public class Country
    {
        public int CID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CAbbrevation { get; set; }
    }

    static List<Country> _staticlist { get; set; } = new List<Country>();

    List<Country> coutries = new List<Country>()
        {
           new Country{CID=1,Name="",CAbbrevation="IND"},
           new Country{CID=2,Name="",CAbbrevation="USA"},
        };
        _staticlist.AddRange(coutries);


        List<State> states = new List<State>()
        {
           new  State{  SID=1,Name="Telangana",SCode="+91",SAbbrevation="TG"},
           new  State{  SID=2,Name="Texas",SCode="512",SAbbrevation="TS"},
        };
```

She tried this, but the static list is not updated , new list is created
I want to update the static list _staticlist without loop

```
    _staticlist.Join(states, a => a.CID, b => b.SID,
            (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .Select(S =>
            {
                S.a.Name = S.b.Name;
                return S;
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: What about `_staticlist = _staticlist.Join(states, a => a.CID, b => b.SID, .... )` ?

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type system.collections generic list anonymous type

Comment: You have to return the country list in your `Select()` like this: `return S.a;`

Comment: Is there a way to update _staticlist .  using LINQ lambda expression .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ statements never modify the collection on which you are using them but rather return a new collection for each LINQ statement you are using. In your case you can assign the collection returned from the LINQ statement directly to `_staticList` again like this:

```
_staticlist = _staticlist.Join(states, a => a.CID, b => b.SID,
    (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .Select(S =>
    {
        S.a.Name = S.b.Name;
        return S.a;
    }).ToList();
```

Be aware of what object type you are selecting when using the `Select()` statement. Because this has to match with the type of `_staticList`.

Comment: thank you sir .
will not update  _staticlist .
There is a mistake.
cannot implicitly convert type system.collections generic list anonymous type

Comment: @formehasan Please be aware of the return statement in `Select()` it's `return S.a;` you need to adjust this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

*but the static list is not updated* because you are not assigning the result of the operation to a variable

```
var myList = _staticlist.Join(states, a => a.CID, b => b.SID,
        (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .Select(S =>
        {
            S.a.Name = S.b.Name;
            return S;
        }).ToList();
```

notice that `Join` is an extension function of Enumerable where enumerables cannot be modified.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, 
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, 
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, 
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
```

Comment: thank you sir .
But how can I update _staticlist .
Is there a way to update _staticlist . 
using LINQ lambda expression .